# Crear un array de objetos con números aleatorios

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy tratando de crear una tabla de forma dinámica **n x m** con datos aleatorios, donde n es el numero de columnas y m el numero de filas y esos datos quiero mostrarlos en una tabla en html:

Por ejemplo, si me piden que la tabla sea **4 x 3** quiero que de forma aleatoria se me cree un arreglo de objetos como el siguiente:

```
    obj = [
  { 1: 255, 2: 685, 3: 483 },
  { 1: 982, 2: 159, 3: 753 },
  { 1: 951, 2: 632, 3: 478 },
  { 1: 746, 2: 851, 3: 118 }
]
```

Estoy trabajándolo en una clase de la siguiente forma pero me he quedado estancado:

```
  getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}    

for (let index = 1; index <= f.value.columnas; index++) {
  this.numeroRandom.push(this.getRandom(f.value.rangoMin, f.value.rangoMax));
}

console.log(this.numeroRandom);

for (let index = 1; index <= f.value.columnas; index++) {
  this.arrayColumnas.push(index);
}

for (let index = 1; index <= f.value.filas; index++) {

  this.arrayFilas.push(index);
}
```

Traté de utilizar esta opción pero no pude [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo las cosas al revés, creando primero las columnas, pero estás usando `.push()`, que es un método para arreglos. Los pasos a seguir son:

- Crear el objeto, como un arreglo vacío `[]`
- Dentro de un ciclo, creas cada fila como objeto vacío `{}`
- Dentro del mismo ciclo, agregas cada columna a la fila

```js
// Crear clase con su constructor, recibiendo 4 parámetros
class MyRand {
  constructor(filas, columnas, min, max) {
    this.filas = filas;
    this.columnas = columnas;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    // Crear arreglo vacío
    this.numeroRandom = [];
  }
  getRandom() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min) + this.min)
  }    
  getResult() {
    // Crear filas
    for (let index = 0; index < this.filas; index++) {
      // Cada fila es un objeto dentro del arreglo, por eso se usa .push()
      this.numeroRandom.push({});
      // Crear columnas para cada fila
      for(let col = 1; col <= this.columnas; col++) {
          // Insertar por clave => valor, aquí no debes usar .push()
          this.numeroRandom[index][col] = this.getRandom();
      }
    }
    return this.numeroRandom;
  }
}
// Escuchar clic en botón
document.querySelector('#generar').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Instanciar clase enviando parámetros
    let myRand = new MyRand(
        parseInt(document.querySelector('#filas').value),
        parseInt(document.querySelector('#columnas').value),
        parseInt(document.querySelector('#min').value),
        parseInt(document.querySelector('#max').value)
    );
    // Obtener objeto
    let result = myRand.getResult();
    // Ahora, ya puedes usar la variable para generar tu tabla
    console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<input id="min" type="number" placeholder="Mínimo" value="1000">
<input id="max" type="number" placeholder="Máximo" value="2000"><br>
<input id="filas" type="number" placeholder="filas" value="3">
<input id="columnas" type="number" placeholder="columnas" value="4"><br>
<button id="generar">Generar</button>
```

**Importante:** De acuerdo a las [especificaciones de JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON#Otras_notas)

> JSON requiere usar comillas dobles para las cadenas y los nombres de propiedades. Las comillas simples no son válidas.

Por lo que, a pesar de asignar claves numéricas, siempre serán tratadas como cadenas.